# Upper content covers the space of lower content in small devices in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

The upper content in the webpage covers the lower content when screen size is shrinked. What might be the solution to this problem? Is'nt the lower content supposed to move down accordingly?

Comment: Please share your code, HTML, CSS, JS. then we can help much better. Genereal answer will be to check when they start to cover (the width in px) then to write this in css: @media screen and (max-width: THE_WIDTHpx){ here modify the elements that cover  }

Comment: Here is the code :    https://codepen.io/Redd_1/pen/JjXjQZj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.testimonials {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    background: url('testbg.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

1. `height: 100vh;` (Avoid using 100vh on mobile);
2. Use pixel values to be consistent within the page, If you use `px`, all pages use `px`, If you use `rem`, all pages use `rem`;
3. Cancel `height: 100vh;` maybe solve the question.

Comment: He is right if you don't want to make changes in your css and convert it to a grid-system. and still using flex (please check the prefix for flex so it will be cross browsers) just delete height: 100vh from you code and it will work

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `viewport` to solve the question.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

Set `viewport` property in the `<head></head>`.

Comment: Ok, I will run your code reproduce the question scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I will write the CSS that way:

CSS

```
.testimonials {
    margin-top: 5rem;
    background: url('testbg.png');
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
}

.comment {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    
}
.comment::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.comment-box {
    float:left;
    margin: 0.5em 1%;
    padding: 1%;
    width:46%;

    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 30px;
}

.testimonials h1,
.testimonials p {
    text-align: center;
}

.testimonials h1 {
    font-family: Raleway;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.testimonials p {
    font-family: Montserrat;
}

.testimonials h5 {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-top: 1rem;
    text-align:right;
}

/*Second section - location style*/
.locations{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top:5em;
}
.locations::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.map{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width:980px){
  /*tablet style*/
  .comment-box{
    width: 96%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:420px){
  /*mobile style*/
  .comment-box{
    width: 96%;
  }
}
```

As you can see beside display flex and general working with flex im using float left and im giving the width.

the most important this solution is cross browsers, your website will look good in internet explorer as well (IE doesn't support flex completely, you need to use the prefix and still some things will not work correctly, also you can face issues with Firefox).

I can recommend you to work with the grid system as simple-grid. very easy to use and it will make sure your website will be 100% cross-browsers.

but this is only my opinion.

Code pen example:

https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/KKzKOwb